# How to remove a certain letter from an arabic text in a dataframe using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have arabic text in a dataframe and I want to remove the letter `و` from all words that start with this letter. I tried to do this:

```
def clean(text_string):
    space_pattern = '\bو'
    
    parsed_text = re.sub(space_pattern, '', text_string)
    return parsed_text
```

and then:

```
df['tidy_tweet'] = np.vectorize(clean)(df['tidy_tweet'])
```

but when I run it, nothing changes. It's as if I didn't do anything at all!

Example:

Input: `هيه الهزه الحقيقيه وتخافون الهزه وماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي`

Desired output: `هيه الهزه الحقيقيه تخافون الهزه ماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex with word boundaries. And use `\1` to keep only the remain of the text.

```py
r"\bو(.*?)\b"
```

```py
import re

text = """هيه الهزه الحقيقيه وتخافون الهزه وماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي"""
ref = """هيه الهزه الحقيقيه تخافون الهزه ماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي"""
print(text)
print(ref)

new_text = re.sub(r"\bو(.*?)\b", r'\1', text)

print(new_text == ref)
```

```
هيه الهزه الحقيقيه وتخافون الهزه وماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي
هيه الهزه الحقيقيه تخافون الهزه ماتخافون الهزه اعملها نظامكم الهمجي
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an r-string for regular expressions:

```
space_pattern = r'\bو'
```

Without the r, the \b is interpreted as the ASCII BACKSPACE character, which does not appear in your text.